# How to get columns separated by 2 or more spaces with Regex?

Tags: php, regex

How to get columns grouped by Regex?

I have data in "columns" (columns are separated by two or more spaces):

```
ii  acpi                                1.5-2                        displays information on ACPI devices
ii  acpi-support-base                   0.137-5                      scripts for handling base ACPI events such as the power button
ii  acpid                               1:2.0.7-1squeeze4            Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon
```

I want to iterate for each line and get array of values like:

```
$outputWouldBe = array(
    array("ii", "acpi", "1.5-2", "displays information on ACPI devices"),
    array("ii", "acpi-support-base", "0.137-5", "scripts for handling base ACPI events such as the power button"),
    array("ii", "acpid", "1:2.0.7-1squeeze4", "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon")
);
```

I've written regex selecting a line `.*[ ]{2,}.*[ ]{2,}.*$` but how to split it by columns?

Comment: Split on line-breaks. Split again on `\s{2,}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just do split like this:

```
$arr = preg_split('/ {2,}/', $str);
```

for each record of input.

#### Code:

```
$s = <<< EOF
ii  acpi                                1.5-2                        displays information on ACPI devices
ii  acpi-support-base                   0.137-5                      scripts for handling base ACPI events such as the power button
ii  acpid                               1:2.0.7-1squeeze4            Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon
EOF;
$outputWouldBe = array();
$lines = explode("\n", $s);
foreach($lines as $line) {
   #echo "$line => ";
   $m = preg_split('/(?: {2,}|\n)/', $line);
   $outputWouldBe[] = $m;
}
print_r($outputWouldBe);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ii
            [1] => acpi
            [2] => 1.5-2
            [3] => displays information on ACPI devices
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ii
            [1] => acpi-support-base
            [2] => 0.137-5
            [3] => scripts for handling base ACPI events such as the power button
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ii
            [1] => acpid
            [2] => 1:2.0.7-1squeeze4
            [3] => Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon
        )

)
```